# Having trouble with deselecting items using SelectionChanged in a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

I'm having two ListBox's next to each other. In the XAML file, it looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="first_box" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Firstlist}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionMode="Single" 
    SelectionChanged="Firstlist_SelectionChanged"/>
<ListBox Name="second_box" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SecondList}"  
    DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionMode="Single" 
    SelectionChanged="Secondlist_SelectionChanged"/>
```

What I'm trying to do is when an item in one of the ListBox's is selected, the other ListBox should lose it's selection. But I think losing that selection triggers `SelectionChanged` again, thus removing the selection in the other ListBox, and so forward...

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to test if the selected item is null:

```
Firstlist_SelectionChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    if(first_box.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        second_box.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}

Secondlist_SelectionChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    if(second_box.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        first_box.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

Initial situation :

```
Box1 => Item1
Box2 => null
```

Click on item in Box2

```
Box1 => Item1
Box2 => Item2 => Event fire
```

Is Box2 null ? No, so set Box1 to null

```
Box1 => null => Event fire
Box2 => Item2
```

Is Box1 null ? Yes, no action.
Final situation:

```
Box1 => null
Box2 => Item2
```

Comment: But if I click an item in the first box, and after that I click an item in the second box, don't both boxes have a selected item now? So your code wouldn't work then.

Comment: When you click the second box, the SelectionChanged event is fired. Since the SelectedItem  of the second box is not null, it will set the selected item of the first box to null. The SelectionChanged  event is fired for the first box, but since it's selected item is null, nothing happens.

Comment: I just verified, it works! Thank you for the extra explanation!